# .NET Core 2.0 Web API for Video Streaming from FileStream

Tags: c#, video-streaming, html5-video, asp.net-core-2.0

I have found a bunch of examples that use objects not available to me within my application and don't seem to match up to my version of .NET Core web API. In essence I am working on a project that will have `<video>` tags on a web page and want to load the videos using a stream from the server rather than directly serving the files via a path. One reason is the source of the files may change and serving them via path isn't what my customer wants. So I need to be able to open a stream and async write the video file.

This for some reason produces JSON data so that's wrong. But I just don't understand what I need to do to send a streamed video file to a `<video>` tag in HTML.

Current Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetVideoContent()
{
    if (Program.TryOpenFile("BigBuckBunny.mp4", FileMode.Open, out FileStream fs))
    {
        using (var file = fs)
        {
            var range = Request.Headers.GetCommaSeparatedValues("Range").FirstOrDefault();
            if (range != null)
            {
                var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
                var body = GetRange(file, range);
                msg.Content = new StreamContent(body);
                msg.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                //msg.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"0-0/{fs.Length}");
                return msg;
            }
            else
            {
                var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                msg.Content = new StreamContent(file);
                msg.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                return msg;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify how you are opening the video filestream?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`HttpResponseMessage` is not used as a return type in `asp.net-core` it will read that as an object model and serialize it in the response by design, as you have already observed.

Luckily in ASP.NET Core 2.0, you have

> ## [Enhanced HTTP header support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/aspnetcore-2.0#enhanced-http-header-support)
>
> If an application visitor requests content with a Range Request header, ASP.NET will recognize that and handle that header. If the requested content can be partially delivered, ASP.NET will appropriately skip and return just the requested set of bytes. You don't need to write any special handlers into your methods to adapt or handle this feature; it's automatically handled for you.

So now all you have to do is return the file stream

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetVideoContent() {
    if (Program.TryOpenFile("BigBuckBunny.mp4", FileMode.Open, out FileStream fs)) {        
        FileStreamResult result = File(
            fileStream: fs, 
            contentType: new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4").MediaType, 
            enableRangeProcessing: true //<-- enable range requests processing
        );
        return result;
    }
     
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Making sure to enable range requests processing. Though, as stated in the documentation, that should be handled based on the request headers and whether that data can be partially delivered.

From there it is now a simple matter of pointing to the endpoint from the video client and let it do its magic

Comment: This works to and very much so answers my question! How does one enable the seek feature of the video player? I cannot seem to make the <video> tag seek it always has to be at the spot in the continued playback.

Comment: Also I notice that the server uses a ton of ram just by loading one video up. Are there any ways to increase efficiency?

Comment: @BaileyMiller inspect the requests being made to make sure it is using the range headers. There should be no need to load the entire file into memory if range headers are being used correctly.

Comment: @SruthiVarghese clarify what you mean by read the file. Are you referring to reading a file is that is posted to the controller action?

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not able to use `Program.TryOpenFile()`. Because it's showing as Program don't have any method like like. I'm not that exposed to Asp .Net. Can you please provide me with a solution to open the file?

Comment: @SruthiVarghese The part of the code was taken from the original question. It could have been custom code. Check out the file system abstraction in .net core to find another way to read a file.

Comment: @BaileyMiller Can you provide any plunkr example for showing how to read the video file?

Comment: @SruthiVarghese I wrote the try open program it is a custom function that does a File.Exists check and returns a file stream if it does.

Comment: Could you update you answer with an example of the client-side JavaScript? How would one add the `Range Request header`? Are they added automaticly by the `<video>` element?

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien `Are they added automaticly by the <video> element?` Yes

Comment: This just returns the entire file, without any of the necessary response headers for a range request, even on ASP.Net Core 2.2. Is there some other configuration that's necessary? The requests are using the `Range` header.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/FileResult.cs#L59) you need to enable range processing similar to how it is also done in [ControllerBase](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L1127)