# .net core response with multiple video files

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, web, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing web api with .net core 5.0.
I'd like to know how can I response with multiple video files(mp4).
I looked at the links below, but couldn't find a way to response with multiple files.

[.NET Core 2.0 Web API for Video Streaming from FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618810/net-core-2-0-web-api-for-video-streaming-from-filestream)

[Streaming video files in asp.net core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338193/streaming-video-files-in-asp-net-core-2)

I would like to ask you if the methods below are a way to solve this. If not, please let me know what is the right way.

##### method 1.

Should I compress multiple files and response it? Then, In front-end side(React js), if I want to show videos in browser, should I unzip file and load it?

##### method 2.

Should I convert video files to Stream and response it by json? Then, In front-end side(React js), how can I convert Stream to mp4?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you want to return multiple videos in one response?

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah ha, you mean, multiple request will solve it?

Comment: I think so. Concatenating or zipping multiple videos is probably not what you want, but ... that depends on what you actually want.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you so much! you think outside the box!